# How do I read *.doc into JTextPane?

Tags: java, apache, swing, doc, jtextpane

I'm using the apache POI to read Word documents. I'm using this example as a template:

http://javamix.wordpress.com/2009/05/14/reading-data-from-the-doc-file-by-using-apache-poi-api/

The problem is I want the contents to read into a JTextPane. And insertString() is not recognized by HWPFDocument.

From the 'for' statement that prints to console from the example in the link above, how do change it to print to the JTextPane (if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

public class ReadDocFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = null;
        WordExtractor extractor = null ;
        try {

            file = new File("c:\\New.doc");
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
            extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
            String [] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
            for(int i=0;i<fileData.length;i++){
                if(fileData[i] != null)
                    System.out.println(fileData[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exep){}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), more in particular in the section 'An example of using a text pane'. The following code snippet is copied from that tutorial

```
String[] initString =
        { /* ...  fill array with initial text  ... */ };

String[] initStyles =
        { /* ...  fill array with names of styles  ... */ };

JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
addStylesToDocument(doc);

//Load the text pane with styled text.
try {
    for (int i=0; i < initString.length; i++) {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), initString[i],
                         doc.getStyle(initStyles[i]));
    }
} catch (BadLocationException ble) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't insert initial text into text pane.");
}
```

The method you are looking for is the `StyledDocument#insertString` method, as illustrated above

Comment: Ok, the part that got me confused is the initStyles[]. Is that like bold, italic, colors, etc? I dont understand how to use that part.

Comment: The linked Swing tutorial contains the [whole sample code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextSamplerDemoProject/src/components/TextSamplerDemo.java). Have you looked at that ?

Comment: Sorry, I read it, but this doesn't do what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to open a document written in MSWord (which is why I have the apache POI) from the example I posted, but display the contents of the file in a JTextPane.